# Getting function as return statement and not values

Tags: python, function, return

I am trying to fetch attribute values from a block in AutoCAD while working with the pyautocad library and using the below-mentioned code for the same.

I/p:

```
for i in acad.iter_objects_fast(object_name_or_list='BlockReference'):
    print(i.Name)
    print(i.GetAttributes)
```

But as an output rather than recieving any values, I am getting the function "<function Dispatch.**getattr**..caller at 0x000001A9BAEE3E20>" itself as a return statement.

O/p:

```
att_block-1
<function Dispatch.__getattr__.<locals>.caller at 0x000001A9BAEE3E20>
```

I also tried if I could convert the same to a list considering the output could contain multiple attributes, as well as other data structures.

Can anyone please tell me what possible solution could help solve this problem?

Comment: I think you forgot to call that method, add `()` to it: `i.GetAttributes()`, not sure if `Name` is a method, but if it is, add parentheses to it too, you also may need to provide some arguments to that method

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response, i.Name is returning correct value i.e. "att_block-1". But as you have suggested I'll add brackets and try again. Although, I have tried putting brackets before, but it was throwing errors. Still I'll try some other ways too.

Comment: For all those who need an answer to this question kindly refer: https://github.com/reclosedev/pyautocad/issues/6